# Connect 12 dots with 7 lines

Tags: visual, geometry

Connect 12 dots with 7 lines such way that on each line there are 4 dots.

Can anyone help me solve this quiz?

Comment: it seems like that this puzzle comes from elsewhere. please provide the source. unattributed work may get downvoted or even closed. happy puzzling ;)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton my friend challenged me on this puzzle i don't know from where it comes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You want to 'recycle' as many points as possible
>  Start with three lines that cross
>
>  [image]
>
>  Add three more lines in the same fashion
>
>   [image]
>
>  Now you have 6 lines and 11 points. Find one more line with three points and add the final point to it like so
>
>  [image]